# ClassLoader throws NullPointerException when trying to partial mock a class with JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

Using Eclipse 3.6.1
Java 1.6.0_26
JMockit 0.999.10

UPDATE: I was able to create a SSCCE, which I am posting below:

UPDATE2: Added DaemonHelper. Additionally, if I remove DaemonHelper from the constructor, I get a ClassCircularityError instead. Related?

I'm trying to do a partial mock of a class, while mocking several dependencies of the class, when I get an NPE from the Class loader. The NPE call stack is show below

I have a `Daemon` Class like so:

```
public class Daemon extends DaemonParent {

public Daemon(ConfigParent config, DaemonHelper helper) {
    super(config, helper);
}

@Override
public void execute() {
    log("Starting");
    if (config.test()) {
        log("Testing");
    }

    log("Ending");  
}
}
```

The Daemon has a Parent like so:

```
public abstract class DaemonParent extends Thread {

protected ConfigParent config;
protected DaemonHelper helper;

public DaemonParent(ConfigParent config, DaemonHelper helper) {
    this.config = config;
    this.helper = helper;
}


public abstract void execute();

public void log(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

There is a helper class like :

```
public class DaemonHelper extends Thread {

}
```

The Config looks like :

```
public class ConfigParent {

protected ConfigHelper helper;

public ConfigParent(ConfigHelper helper) {
    this.helper = helper;
}

public boolean test() {
    return false;
}
}
```

The Config Parent looks like :

```
public class ConfigParent implements Serializable {

protected ConfigHelper helper;

public ConfigParent(ConfigHelper helper) {
    this.helper = helper;
}

public boolean test() {
    return false;
}
}
```

And the Test looks like :

```
public class DaemonTest {

@Test
public void testExecute(final ConfigHelper ch, final DaemonHelper dh) {
    final Config c = new Config(ch);
    final Daemon d = new Daemon(c, dh);

    new NonStrictExpectations(d) {
        {

        }
    };

    d.execute();

    new Verifications() {{
        d.log("Starting");
        d.log("Ending");
    }};
}
}
```

When I try to run this test, I get the following error. Note this error only pops up when the DaemonParent and Daemon Helper have java.lang.Thread as a superclass:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Thread.interrupted(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.addFailure(EachTestNotifier.java:23)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I tried commenting out the `NonStrictExpectations` block and the `Verifications` block, and I get the same error.

The NPE is thrown from a call to currentThread()... which I have no Idea how it could fail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem that that the root superclass of Daemon is `java.lang.Thread`, which caused JMockit to have trouble. The solution was static partial mocking of the methods required by the test.

```
public class DaemonTest {

@Test
public void testExecute(final ConfigHelper ch, final DaemonHelper dh) {

new NonStrictExpectations(d) {
    @Mocked({"log"}
    Daemon d;
    @Mocked({"()"})
    DaemonHelper dh;
    {

    }
};


final Config c = new Config(ch);
final Daemon d = new Daemon(c, dh);
d.execute();

new Verifications() {{
    d.log("Starting");
    d.log("Ending");
}};
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going to write an answer, but you beat me to it. The test mocks the `Thread` class both fully (the `dh` mock parameter) and partially (passing `d` in the constructor), something that should be avoided. An alternative would be to *not* mock anything for `dh`, by annotating the parameter with `@Mocked("")`. (In any case, I improved the robustness of JMockit when mocking the `java.lang.Thread` class, for release 0.999.12.)

Comment: @Rogerio: Thanks! I look forward to the new release.